# AFrame Oculus Go Controller Documentation?

Tags: aframe, oculus

Does anyone know where I can get some decent AFrame Oculus Go Controller Documentation?

I need to make a camera controller that moves like a WASD with the Oculus Go   Controller. Right now on aframe.io there is no documentation on Oculus Go.

Answer (score 4):

The Oculus Go controls are available in the master branch (you can use it today at https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/master/dist/aframe-master.js) and will ship in A-Frame 0.9.0. Docs available here: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/introduction/interactions-and-controllers.md#adding-3dof-controllers-daydream-controls-gearvr-controls-oculus-go-controls

Comment: I'm looking for the 'events' for the Go Controller. The link to the 'oculus-go-controls component' goes to a 404 page. Are the Go Controller events the same as the 'gearvr-controls component?'